# Google Colab Notebook save to github error

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

Google's colab notebook allows saving to a github repo. It's awesome!  But after updating my notebook 30+ times.  I'm now getting an exception when I save to the repo. [image]

Despite the ominous message, the repo seems to be updated.   Any clues on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with github, the notebook is there but the rendering fails. You need to refresh it multiple times until it loads. There is an issue here: (still unresolved in 2021) https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3555#issuecomment-748173157